# Ansible-lint: do not understand confusing linting error

Tags: python, docker, ansible

I am working with a CI/CD pipeline and part of the pipeline runs `ansible-lint` against some playbooks. Ansible-lint is run via a docker container. I have some playbooks that are giving me a very confusing error. Here is an example playbook and the results of running `ansible-lint`.

Playbook:

```
---
- name: "SET CONFIG"
  hosts: my_host

  tasks:
    - name: Test
      debug:
        msg: "Test message"
```

ansible-lint command: `ansible-lint playbook.yml`

ansible-lint output:

```
Couldn't parse task at playbook.yml:6 (conflicting action statements: debug, __line__

The error appears to be in '<unicode string>': line 6, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

(could not open file to display line))
{ 'debug': {'__file__': 'playbook.yml', '__line__': 8, 'msg': 'Test message'},
  'name': 'Test',
  'skipped_rules': []}
```

I am getting this error on several playbooks but I have boiled it down to this small test playbook to illustrate what's happening. I truly cannot understand what is going on. If I remove the `tasks` definition the playbook lints just fine.

I am running the following:

- Python: 3.8.5
- Ansible: 2.8.5
- Ansible-lint: 4.2.0
- Docker: 19.03.5

Anybody have ideas as to what is going on? I have seen other similar questions on StackOverflow but those solutions all seem to indicate that the tasks need to be separated. This playbook has only *one* task.

Comment: Are you sure you are not simply having a carriage return issue? Like a windows `\r` that is miss-interpreted when the file is mounted on your container. From my side, using your exact playbook, I cannot reproduce.

Comment: You left out your ansible version, but [based on this bug](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-lint/issues/892) I'm guessing it's 2.10 :-) -- also, [ansible-lint 4.3.5 is the latest](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-lint/releases)

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε I thought that might be the issue but I'm on a Mac where the command runs just fine. When I run the docker command on a Linux machine I get the error. Also, I have re-created the file by hand several times just to be sure that I don't have any bad characters. It starting to look to me like it might be partially the fault of [this issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-lint/issues/395)

Comment: @Winsel but that issue is caused by a real issue in the OP playbook: an parameter was left blank, so it ended up `None`, which is invalid for the module used. You don't seem to have anything invalid in your playbook.

Comment: You're right. Didn't notice that. Now I'm even more confused. I'm going to see if I can upgrade to 4.3.5.

Comment: I don't really have an answer with regards to why 4.2.0 of ansible-lint specifically returns this error. In order to get things moving on this pipeline I have gone ahead and upgraded to ansible-lint 4.3.5 as pointed out by @mdaniel and things seem to be working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I had pretty much the same problem, but with python2.7 in a docker image based on Debian Stretch. Ansible 2.10 is the common factor, and @mdaniel suggestion is right about that bug being the problem - so upgrading to ansible 4.3.5 or later is the solution.

Comment: For the record. The bug was fixed. See [Add ability to mock modules from collections #1316](https://github.com/ansible-community/ansible-lint/pull/1316)

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for me in Gitlab-CI:

```
lint_playbooks:
  stage: test:pre
  script:
    - PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8 ansible-lint *.yml -vvvv
```